# How to get task port of SpringBoard in iOS7 (Jailbroken)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi, cydia, tweak

I know we can use `contextIdAtPosition` and `taskPortOfContextId` to get the `mach_port_t` of the front top app, but when inside some app, we can not use `contextIdAtPosition` to get the context id of `SpringBoard` (it's at background), so how can we get the `mach_port_t` of `SpringBoard`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki//System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.SpringBoard.plist, the SpringBoard has exposed a lot of services. two of them might (or might not) be of your interests:

- "com.apple.iohideventsystem"
- "com.apple.springboard"

Here is the sample code to query the ports by service names.

```
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include "bootstrap.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHECK_MACH_ERROR(a) do {kern_return_t rr = (a); if ((rr) != KERN_SUCCESS) \
{ printf("Mach error %x (%s) on line %d of file %s\n", (rr), mach_error_string((rr)), __LINE__, __FILE__); abort(); } } while (0)

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) 
{
  mach_port_t bp = MACH_PORT_NULL;
  mach_port_t sp = MACH_PORT_NULL;

  kern_return_t err = task_get_bootstrap_port(mach_task_self(), &bp);
  CHECK_MACH_ERROR(err);
  printf("bp:%d\n", bp);

  err = bootstrap_look_up(bp, "com.apple.iohideventsystem", &sp);
  CHECK_MACH_ERROR(err);
  printf("iohideventsystem:%d\n", sp);

  err = bootstrap_look_up(bp, "com.apple.springboard", &sp);
  CHECK_MACH_ERROR(err);
  printf("springboard:%d\n", sp);

  // need to deallocate ports before exit

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
my-iPad:~ root# /usr/bin/port_query 
bp:519
iohideventsystem:4099
springboard:4355
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Nick, but do you know how to get the context id of `SpringBoard`?I need use `taskPortOfContextId` to get that `task port` of `context`.

Comment: Maybe I should get the `task port` of `SBApplication`, how can I archive that?Could you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243657/how-to-get-task-port-of-sbapplication-in-ios-7-jailbroken, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There is a SpringboardService framework.

It has a function `SBSSpringBoardServerPort()` which returns Springboard mach port.

Note: Each application may have multiple mach ports, so I am not sure that it's one which you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried `SBSSpringBoardServerPort()` as you said but got the wrong port, could you take a look at my code above in my post addition?Thank you!

Comment: You should show a code which where you use the port. As I said, each app may expose multiple ports for different purposes.

Comment: I need get the port to make a `IOHIDEventSystemConnectionRef` to the `IOHID` system, it looks like I shall get the `task port` of `SpringBoard`, how can I get the `task port`?Thank you!

Comment: @ Suge Please did u get a solution? I get a solution to have a programmatically send event on iOS7 simulator but on device no I thought that the problem is the task port...