# How to get bundle identifier of application by context id or by mach port in iOS 7(Jailbroken)?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, cydia, tweak

I now we can use `contextIdAtPosition` method to get context id of the front most application, but how can I use context id to get the bundle identifier of the front most application?Thank you!

Comment: @Surge: I get nil from [objc_getClass("CAWindowServer") serverIfRunning]? How were you able to make it work? Do you use any entitlements? I got jailbroken iOS 7 device on which I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the identifier of the front most app, you need to check out `SpringBoard` class.

```
@interface SBApplication : NSObject
-(NSString *)displayIdentifier;
@end

@interface SpringBoard : UIApplication
-(SBApplication *)_accessibilityFrontMostApplication;
@end
```

Comment: Thank you, and how can I get task port of `SpringBoard` as the method `taskPortOfContextId`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If your tweak runs in `SpringBoard` then you can get the instance of `SpringBoard` by using `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`.

Comment: I want to make an `IOHIDSystemConnectionRef` to `SpringBoard`, which needs `task port` of `SpringBoard`, wen can use `contextIdAtPosition ` and `taskPortOfContextId` to get `task port` of the front most app, but how can we get the `task port` of `SpringBoard` when it's not at the home screen?

Comment: I don't know. But I think that should be asked as a separate question. It seems now you can get both identifier and task port of the front most app and this question is solved.

Comment: Thank you.Could you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660397/how-to-get-task-port-of-springboard-in-ios7-jailbroken

Comment: Thanks for the link. I haven't made any related tweaks, just read some code of veency and am not familiar with that.